# temp folder is created as temp file

Tags: java, c, tomcat, operating-system, system

guys
i have experienced a weird thing today.
i am installing tomcat5 , and it stopped in the middle of progress bar. and i use process explorer to check the processes. i found a process with command line :

C:\TEMP\nse305.tmp\ns306.tmp "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.0\bin\tomcat5.exe" //IS//Tomcat5 .....

the weird thing is the first part: C:\TEMP\nse305.tmp\ns306.tmp
it supposed to be a path(folder) , i mean the nse305.tmp and ns306.tmp should be a temp folder name. 
but when i check this path, i found nse305.tmp is folder, but  ns306.tmp is a file!!!

that's why the process freeze, it is trying to run a tmp file: C:\TEMP\nse305.tmp\ns306.tmp
and since ns306.tmp is not an executable, the process never end.

so i wonder :
  why the ns306.tmp is created as a file , not folder? i am sure it's my pc's problem. the tomcat installation runs well in my workmate's pc. 
  is there any setting of OS , that will prefer to create file, instead of folder?

i have some experience like this:
copy a.txt c:\b
what i want is that : the "copy" create a new folder "b", and place a.txt in it.
but actually it don't create any folder, just copy and rename the file with name "b" .

i think these two situatiosn are a little similar. but i don't know how to fix my Tomcat5 installation.

i have read the Tomcat5.0.28.nsi file. the original code to run is :

nsExec::ExecToLog '"$INSTDIR\bin\tomcat5.exe" //IS//Tomcat5 --DisplayName "Apache Tomcat" --Description "Apache Tomcat @VERSION@ Server - http://jakarta.apache.org/tomcat/" --LogPath "$INSTDIR\logs" --Install "$INSTDIR\bin\tomcat5.exe" --Jvm "$2"'

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can completely understand what you're asking, but if you put `\` on the end of the path it will ensure it is a folder and not a file - i.e. `C:\TEMP\nse305.tmp\ns306.tmp\`

Comment: but my problem is that: when i install Tomcat5.0.28, it failed , and looks like when the tomcat installer run the process "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.0\bin\tomcat5.exe" //IS//Tomcat5... , it try to run it in some temp path, but it created the temp path wrongly, (it should create "ns306.tmp" folder, but it created a file) , so the process command line is realy trying to run a ns306.tmp file. and it never return ,so the tomcat installation freeze.

Comment: i am not sure how to fix it,  it should be my pc's problem, maybe there is some configuration somewhere about temp folders? i tried

Comment: to change  set Temp and Tmp environment variables, set them to C:\Temp from "C:\document and setting\<myuser>\localsetting\Temp"  , but the problem still occur